# Remote iOS Upgrade Through MDM Bypassing Welcome Screens

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade, ipados, mdm

I administrate an MDM with over 95 locations and 16,000 iOS tablets, distributed globally.

I have remote access to upgrade iOS to any devices centrally, but also the local admins can push to their specific locations/tablets.

All tablets are locked into Single App Mode (kiosk).

The question is, Is there a setting or way to push an iOS upgrade with MDM to the tablet and it upgrade without the **Welcome** screens displaying and forcing a local response on every tablet?

Comment: Do you have regular meetings with Apple Engineers and your MDM engineers? They would be invaluable to get you the correct settings / feasibility. There’s so much changing rapidly, their knowledge will help you greatly - https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/manage-software-updates-depc4c80847a/web

Answer (score 1):

In general, no - you can not enroll devices so that iOS auto advances past the entire assistant.

You can select some of the screens to be suppressed, which may or may not work for your intended designs unless you can generate profiles to enforce settings your users do not choose or you need to relax privacy.

https://it-training.apple.com/tutorials/deployment-and-management/dm-0901_ar_managing-enrollment-setup-assistant

[image: MDM Options for various Apple OS]